# Javascript array - how to print strings only

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm a learning newbie.

In my code at: 
"https://codepen.io/JonasJsk/pen/qrzLzv"

```
MYAPPLICATION.DisplayNames = function ()
{
  var i, len, str;
  for(i = 0, len = MYAPPLICATION.Names.length, str = ""; i < len; ++i)
  {
    str += MYAPPLICATION.Names[i] + "<br>";
  }
  console.log(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = str);
}
```

I have declared an javascript array with both strings and numbers.

1 - I'm trying to figure out how I can specifically only print-out the strings to the console.

I have been at this for hours, please help me!

Comment: `console.log(str);`

Comment: Sorry - Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [your code example](https://codepen.io/JonasJsk/pen/qrzLzv) you can iterate over `MYAPPLICATION.Names` array with the method [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and validate the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) every element in the array is an `string`:

```js
var MYAPPLICATION = MYAPPLICATION || {};
MYAPPLICATION.Names = ["Superman", "Batman", "Flash", 66, 23, 97]
MYAPPLICATION.DisplayNames = function () {
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  MYAPPLICATION.Names.forEach(function (item) {
    if (typeof item === 'string') {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  });
  
  content.innerHTML = '';
  content.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<h2>Lab #2.1</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="MYAPPLICATION.DisplayNames()">
    Get Names
</button>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I just tied your way it is only giving the 3rd string in the array.
please check - https://codepen.io/JonasJsk/pen/qrzLzv

Comment: In the console all names are logged.. What happens is that you are doing `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = item` and at the end you only see the last element

Comment: Updated the code example to print strings only in the `div` element with `id` content

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator like this :

```
var aList = [1, 2, 3, "one", "two", "three"];

for(var i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {
  if(typeof(aList[i]) == "string")
  console.log("This is a string : "+aList[i]);
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question... Do you want to remove the numbers from the array or you want to print the information only on the `console.log` ?

Anyway, try this one:

```
var MYAPPLICATION = MYAPPLICATION || {};

MYAPPLICATION.Names = ["Superman", "Batman", "Flash", 66, 23, 97]

MYAPPLICATION.DisplayNames = function ()
{
  //MYAPPLICATION.myJSON = JSON.stringify(MYAPPLICATION.Names);
  var i, len, str;
  for(i = 0, len = MYAPPLICATION.Names.length, str = ""; i < len; ++i)
  {
    if (!isNaN(MYAPPLICATION.Names[i])) { continue; }
    str += MYAPPLICATION.Names[i] + "<br>";
  }
  console.log(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = str);
}
```

You can also remove the `console.log` if you don't want to print in the console.

Like:

```
var MYAPPLICATION = MYAPPLICATION || {};

MYAPPLICATION.Names = ["Superman", "Batman", "Flash", 66, 23, 97]

MYAPPLICATION.DisplayNames = function ()
{
  var i, len, str;
  for(i = 0, len = MYAPPLICATION.Names.length, str = ""; i < len; ++i)
  {
    name = MYAPPLICATION.Names[i]
    if (!isNaN(name)) { continue; }
    str += name + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code snippet worked great.

Can I ask your help with one more thing,

How do I go about if I only wish to print out the numbers instead ?

Thanks

Comment: change the line `if (!isNaN(name)) { continue; }` to `if (isNaN(name)) { continue; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
MYAPPLICATION.DisplayNames = function () {
  var stringsOnly = MYAPPLICATION.Names.filter(function(item) {
      return typeof item === 'string';
  });
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = stringsOnly.join('<br>');
}
```